# Django Models, cyclic foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

How to model the following relationship:

```
class Country(models.Model):
  # The capital city of this country
  capital = models.ForeignKey(City)
  ## other country stuff

class City(models.Model):
  # The country where this city lies in
  country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
  ## other city stuff
```

This obviously doesn't compile.
(City is undefined in the definition of Country).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the model by using string instead of a model class:

```
class Country(models.Model):
  # The capital city of this country
  capital = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='+')
  ## other country stuff
```

Also see:

- [Django models.py Circular Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682513/django-models-py-circular-foreign-key)
- [Cross-referencing foreign keys in Django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263219/cross-referencing-foreign-keys-in-django-1-4)

Comment: Works, but need to add related_name parameter. Edited the solution to include this.